# When is UITableView's reloadData Synchronous?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, asynchronous, synchronous

When is an UITableView's reloadData method synchronous vs. asynchronous? Apple's documentation does not mention anything about it, and I've seen the reloadData function perform both synchronously as well as asynchronously, which really confuses me.

How does Apple make the distinction about which scheme to use? Does anyone know?

Comment: how does tableview reload its data asynchronously?

Answer (score -1):

The update to the UI is always synchronous but you its possible to update the data asynchronously before calling reloadData and incurring the synchronous UI update.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is down voted since there wasn't a comment. The update to the UI is synchronous because it happens on the main thread, you can update the data asynchronously because you can do that on a background thread or block however you wish. If you're going to down vote at least say why so it can be addressed so people don't think the answer is just incorrect.